# I've downloaded zip from ARC welder app. When I upload it to chrome webstore, it's status remains PROCESSING

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-arc

I want to publish my android apk to chrome web store. I've downloaded zip from ARC welder app. When I launch the app from welder app, It's working as expected. But, when I upload it to chrome webstore from developer dashboard, it's status remains PROCESSING. It doesn't change. However, docs say the edit page will appear within seconds after upload. What's wrong?

Can I extract the zip download with app welder - change manifest file , add icon images - zip again - upload to web store?

Comment: I'm not into app webstores but aren't  apps reviewd before published? maybe this is meant by processing?

Comment: No, web apps are not reviewed manually. And DOC clearly says that edit screen will appear in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you met is a known bug for developer dashboard UI and has affected many developers currently. [image]Google chrome engineer team is working on it and may have a fix soon. The best you can do now is trying to upload via the publish API : https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api

Comment: Is there an issue to track on crbug?

Comment: @Xan I'm not sure if there's a post on crbug. But I do find one on Google forum: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/Cl6ModtVW0g

Comment: I know there are some Webstore-related issues on crbug; but I'm not sure either it's used internally to track such things.

Comment: @Xan I think it's used both for internally and externally to track issues.

Comment: Yes, in Chrome; not sure about Webstore though.

Comment: @Xan Don't worry and I'll keep it updated as soon as there's a fix on it.

Comment: Well, Thanks @gui47, I'll try the 'using_webstore_api' link you shared.